# Apache-Ignite Source-code Test does keep on running due to locking

Tags: ignite

I am setting up apache-ignite source code locally and facing some issue while running tests.The test ReadWriteLockMultiThreadedTest.testReadThenWriteLockAcquire seems to buggy as it keep running due to acquiring lock which is already acquired. WriteLock will conflict with readlock as its not released by the time writelock is acquired of ReentrantReadWriteLock from java.

Code for the test exist below.

```
public void testReadThenWriteLockAcquire() throws Exception {
        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

        lock.readLock().lock();

        lock.writeLock().lock();
    }
```

Can someone explain why this test is added & how it supposed to run ?

Whole test class can be viewed from.
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/jvmtest/ReadWriteLockMultiThreadedTest.java

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this test is supposed to be run during normal operation. Consider always running Ignite with `-DskipTests=true`.

Ignite's test running is intricate as it involves running dozens of separate test suites in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @alamar , I thought this test should have been added with some purpose. Anyway Can you also help me further, I am trying to configure local build setup for ignite, wants to run the tests to verify the build, how would I know which minimum valid tests should I run to ensure code is working fine ?

Comment: I guess you could try running `IgniteBasicTestSuite` :) Plus suited for whatever realms that you have touched.

Comment: Thanks this should help as ReadWriteLockMultiThreadedTest was part of IgniteLostAndFoundTestSuite. For now I was running this by using tryLock() instead of lock() to run test.

Comment: Hi Alamar, One more quick help if you can check. While running the IgniteBasicTestSuite from core module on our gitlab , I am seeing few errors as below, while running failed tests from local dev setup in IDE runs fine. Error in gitlab: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.tests.p2p.P2PTestTaskExternalPath1 , which seems to be classes from other modules. So we need to build all other modules first ?

Comment: @tarunk Yes, you need to build all `extdata` modules I believe. I'm not sure how it is handled on TC.

Comment: Thanks Much @alamar for prompt response, it worked !